# I want to create another popup message depending on the answer (in Python 3)

Tags: python

So far, I've created a window which asks a question with a yes/no answer, but how do I create another window which has a different output depending on the answer given by the operator?

(Sorry for not including it)

**Code:**

```
import ctypes  

def Mbox(title, text, style):
     return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, style)

Mbox('This may be incorrect', 'Do you proceed?', 4)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code? (you can edit the answer)

Comment: http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msgbox.html#the-prompt-function